# Adding parenthesis around all equation numbers using sed

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I have a big LaTeX file containing huge loads of equations.
They are all referenced as follows:

```
Equation~\ref{XX}
Equation~\ref{XY}
...
```

I want to obtain this,

```
Equation~(\ref{XX})
Equation~(\ref{XY})
...
```

I have only a basic knowledge of sed, but I'm convinced it could do the trick using the '&' symbol.

I tried:

```
sed 's#\ref{*}#(&)#g' input_tex_file.tex
```

Which does not change anything.

If I do:

```
sed 's#\ref{XX}#(&)#g' input_tex_file.tex
```

I obviously obtain

```
Equation~(\ref{XX})
```

But I would like to avoid writing a script to detect all references and modify them sequentially, even if I guess it would not be overwhelming.

Please also note that I have loads of things like *Table~\ref{XX}* and *Figure~\ref{XX}* that I would like to left unmodified.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` symbol in the replacement pattern stands for the whole match. You seem to wannt to avoid modifying values after any word but `Equation~`, so it should be included into the pattern and that means, you cannot use `&`, but regular `\1` and `\2` to refer to captured parts of the regex.

You may capture the `Equation~` and the rest of the pattern into two separate groups and refer to them in the replacement:

```
sed 's#\(Equation~\)\(\\ref{[^{}]*}\)#\1(\2)#g'
```

or, with POSIX ERE,

```
sed -E 's#(Equation~)(\\ref\{[^{}]*})#\1(\2)#g'
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/LBJNQ34345):

```
s='Equation~\ref{XX} Table~\ref{XX} and Figure~\ref{XX}'
echo "$s" | sed 's#\(Equation~\)\(\\ref{[^{}]*}\)#\1(\2)#g'
# => Equation~(\ref{XX}) Table~\ref{XX} and Figure~\ref{XX}
```

Comment: Works perfectly !
Thanks a lot for your detailed answer.